# ASP.NET Master Page Parse Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, master-pages

I have a Visual Studio 2010 project with a Master Page that works fine.

```
~/Site.Master
```

In the same project is a Folder with another directory structure that needs to use another Master Page.

```
/xr
```

Within this folder, I have included the Master Page for those files.

```
/xr/XR.Master
```

My `Default.aspx` file attempts to access this Master Page using the following include:

```
<%@ Page Title="XR Project" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/xr/XR.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="Test1.Default" %>
```

Debugging on my machine in `localhost` works fine, but whenever I deploy it and try to navigate to the Default page in the `xr` folder, I get

**Parser Error Message:** `The file '/xr/xr/XR.Master' does not exist.`

However, the **Source Error** returns Line 1 as I have shown above.

**Here is what I tried:**

- I moved the `XR.Master` page into the root folder and changed all of the files in the `xr` folder to reference the XR Master Page using the following include:
- I debugged and tested the code on my machine using `localhost`, and it worked fine.
- I pushed it out to the remote website and got the new error:

**Parser Error Message:** `The file '/xr/~/XR.Master' does not exist.`

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:** I do not like posting a link to the page, but I will for a short time until this is resolved:

- [Projects](http://www.jp2code.net/Projects.aspx)

From there, you will see everything works well enough except for the link to `XR1200`.

Comment: This seems really strange... have you tried clearing the entire contents of the folder you are publishing to before you publish?

Comment: No, I have not. There are a few files already there (backups, audio files, etc) that I don't want to blow away.

Comment: Should the `subfolder` master page be located in the `root` folder or in the folder where the `content` pages are located?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my guess is that the iis setup is different on the different machines.  typically, you see something like this when you have one machine set up with the site itself as a website and another machine set up with the site itself as an application within a website (like the Default Website).  it looks like you have addressed this possibility by using the ~ in the path, but perhaps the iis on which you are deploying does not have the site directory itself set up as either a website or an application, but is merely a subdirectory of a site.  in that case, the ~ would refer to the website directory (perhaps named xr?) and the site is in a subdirectory of that named xr.  if this is the case, the solution is probably to set up iis such that you have the application directory configured as an application on the server to which you are deploying.

Comment: Oh! That could be it! I don't think I've configured the `xr` folder as an IIS folder! Let me go check...

Comment: No, that wasn't it. Apparently, I'd set the IIS permissions on that folder some time ago. :(

Comment: bummer.  i really thought that was going to be it.  so is iis configured identically on both machines or are there some differences there?

Comment: I'm not sure how to check that, it being a remotely hosted website. Perhaps there are scripts I could call. Ick.

Comment: so remote hosted means you are on a shared hosting provider?  hard to know how they have iis set up.  is your account with them called xr?  looks like there is an extra xr in the path.  seems they are considering your site xr, which is a subdirectory of the site rather than an application.  you might be able to make your local site just a subdirectory instead of an application and then path to your master page accordingly.  if you can get that to work on your local, it will probably work on the shared host.

Comment: The site is `www.jp2code.net`, and `xr` is a folder in that domain on GoDaddy (my opinion on GoDaddy isn't great, but they are providing me a nice service). A link to the site is provided in the original post under the *EDIT* section. I'm about to try Dylan Hayes' suggestion.

Comment: The folder that `xr` sat in was, in fact, set up as an **Application Root**. I turned that off, waited 24-hrs for it to go into affect, and ...it works! Thank you!

Comment: sweet.  it can be painful trying to get everything configured right.  upvoted dylan's answer for all the effort in digging into it.

Answer (score 3):

Here's the best advice I can give ya without knowing too much about your project structure.
I'm hoping you are using VS2010 so that things will look the same for you as on my machine.
One easy way to get the path of your master page all figured out is to add a test web page from masterfile, the path will be preset for you and you can use that in your existing pages.

- Here is my blogs project structure.
  Right click the folder where you want to add the test page and click add new file.
  [image]
- Add a new web form using Master Page. This is just for testing.
  [image]
- Now locate your Masterpage and select it.
  [image]
- From here just find your newly added content page in your solution structure and check the code files for the path to your masterpage.
  [image]
- Once you've verified that your path is correct, if it still bombs once you publish it then you've got either an issue where not all of your projects are building properly, or you're files aren't being uploaded properly and that is going to end up being something that you may just have to find on your own. I still suggest blowing away anything in your pub folder on your server and trying a clean publish.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Rats. It's Saturday and the project is at work. I'm checking this out first thing, though!

Comment: OK, this one works: http://www.jp2code.net/Dylan.aspx, this one (within the `xr` folder) does not: http://www.jp2code.net/xr/DylanXR.aspx

Comment: Both files have the exact same content and were created the exact same way, as described by your steps above. The first one, I Right-Clicked the root folder and added a new Web Form using Master Page and pointed to the Master Page in the `xr` folder. The second one. I right-Clicked the `xr` folder itself to add the new Web Form and pointed it to the same Master Page in the same `xr` folder. ???

Comment: and you're still getting the parse error on your newly created test pages?

Comment: LOL - well, not now. It turns out the `xr` folder was set up as an **Application Root**. I turned that off yesterday, but it took GoDaddy 24-hours to apply that change. Thank you for the help! I'll remove your pages now.

Comment: Good deal, glad ya got it working, my solution was primarily just to rule out that it was a code issue and we now see that indeed it was something screwy with the server